# MoTTY Command Line Error. This program should be launched by MobaXterm

Tags: linux, mobaxterm

MoTTY Command Line Error. This program should be launched by MobaXterm.

When I connect to a Linux server using Mobaxterm, this error is reported. I tried restarting and downloading again, but none of them worked. When I switched to someone else's computer, it was normal.